# Stochastic Processes: Markov Chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I would like to know how to solve question 3

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to calculate the probability that X_5 = 1 given that X_1 = i and then multiplied it by the probability that X_1 = i.

Comment: Right, and how do you compute that? More generally, if you know a state of the Markov chain at time $t$, what is the distribution of the Markov chain at time $t + i$? Remember the Chapman--Kolmogorov equations.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment below: It is against the etiquette of this site to completely change the content of a question after receiving at least one answer, which is why I have just reverted your edit. If my answer (or the other answer) was helpful, please accept one of them and post a new question. Also it would be nice to see your own thoughts on the questions instead of just "how do I solve this part of my homework?"

Answer (score 3):

1. The following figure shows the Markov chain.

[image]

with the following transition matrix (with $p=0.5$):

[image]

2. Simulation of 2 simple paths using the transition probability matrix with python (notice that `python` has $0$-based indexing):

   ```
   import networkx as nx
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pylab as plt

   p = 0.5
   g = nx.DiGraph()

   for i in range(1,22):
       g.add_node(i)

   # add all the edges to the graph with the transition probs
   g.add_edge(1, 2, weight=1)
   g.add_edge(2, 1, weight=1)
   # ... ...

   # obtain the Markov transition matrix       
   T =  nx.adjacency_matrix(g).todense()

   n_steps = 200
   n_paths = 2
   plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
   plt.ylim(15, 25)
   for _ in range(n_paths):
      s = 21
      chain = [s]
      for _ in range(n_steps):
         nbrs = nx.neighbors(g, s)
         nbrs = list(nbrs)
         # sample from the neighbor states, with probability proportional to transition
         ps = []
         for nbr in nbrs:
            ps.append(T[s-1, nbr-1])
         s = np.random.choice(nbrs, 1, p=ps)[0]
         chain.append(s)
      plt.plot(range(n_steps+1), chain)
      plt.show()
   ```

If the initial state is in the vertex subset $\{19,20,21\}$, a simple  path starting at 21 can never leave the subgraph formed by these 3 vertices, as can be seen from the next figure (since the component is absorbing, no outgoing edge present).

[image]

3. Since for any $p \geq 0$ the Markov chain is transient (if it leaves the vertex subset $V\setminus\{19,20,21\}$, it can never return), since there is no outgoing path from the connected component $\{19,20,21\}$, $P(X(5))=0$. In the long run, it will be equiprobable to stay in any of these 3 states, the intuition is supported by the following power-iteration:

   ```
   initial = np.zeros(21)
   initial[19] = initial[20] = 1/2
   # power iteration
   vec = initial
   for i in range(100):
       vec = vec@T
   vec
   # [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 
       0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333]]
   ```

   We can theoretically prove it too. In order to prove that the steady state probabilities are exactly same for each vertices in the isolated subgraph $\{19,20,21\}$, you could solve the linear system $\pi = \pi P$, with

   [image]

   that reduces to system of linear equations $\pi_{19}=\frac{1}{2}\pi_{20}+\frac{1}{2}\pi_{19}$, $\pi_{21}=\frac{1}{2}\pi_{20}+\frac{1}{2}\pi_{21}$ and $\pi_{20}=\frac{1}{2}\pi_{19}+\frac{1}{2}\pi_{21}$, which leads to the unique solution $\pi_{19}=\pi_{20}=\pi_{21}$, which along with $\pi_{19}+\pi_{20}+\pi_{21}=1$ gives the desired result $\pi_{19}=\pi_{20}=\pi_{21}=\frac{1}{3}$.

   Since the stationary distribution is independent of the initial state, by Perron–Frobenius theorem, for the connected aperiodic subgraph, we can obtain the steady state vector at stationary distribution by computing the normalized right eigenvector of $P$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$:

   ```
   Λ, V = np.linalg.eig(np.array([[1/2,1/2,0],[1/2,0,1/2],[0,1/2,1/2]]).T)
   Λ
   # array([-0.5,  0.5,  1. ])
   V = V[:,Λ==1]
   V / sum(V)
   # array([[0.33333333],
   #        [0.33333333],
   #        [0.33333333]])
   ```

Comment: Holy shit you legend. Still there are some things I don't understand: $X(5)$ denotes the stochastic process at index $5$, so it is a random variable, right? Then what does $P(X(5))=0$ mean? Second, how do you prove that $X(5)$ stays in any of the three states $19,20,21$ with the same probability (I am surprised that this is supposed to be true, in fact).

Comment: Actually there is more I don't understand: What is the `nx` and the `g` in your Python code?

Comment: Also, to prove that the steady state probs are same in the subgraph $\{19,20,21\}$, you could solve the linear system $\pi = \pi P$, that reduces to system of linear equations $\pi_{19}=\frac{1}{2}\pi_{20}+\frac{1}{2}\pi_{19}$, $\pi_{21}=\frac{1}{2}\pi_{20}+\frac{1}{2}\pi_{21}$ and $\pi_{20}=\frac{1}{2}\pi_{19}+\frac{1}{2}\pi_{21}$, which leads to the unique solution $\pi_{19}=\pi_{20}=\pi_{21}$, which along with $\pi_{19}+\pi_{20}+\pi_{21}=1$ gives the desired result.

Comment: `nx` is the `networkx` package (added the additional code) I used to compute the underlying DiGraph `g` to readily use the neighbor function and compute the Markov transition matrix, you may compute it without the package too.

Comment: Ok I understand the following: If you are in state $19,20$ or $21$, you have the following transition matrix to $19,20,21$: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&\frac12&0\\ \frac12&0&\frac 12 \\ 0 & \frac12 & \frac12\end{pmatrix}.$$ From the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations, one gets the probabilities for $X(5)$ to be in state $19,20$ or $21$ to be the entries of the vector $$A^5 \begin{pmatrix}\frac12\\0\\\frac12\end{pmatrix},$$ and one can compute this explicitly. If I understand you correctly, $$A^n\begin{pmatrix}\frac12\\0\\\frac12\end{pmatrix}\to(1/3,1/3,1/3)^\top$$ in some sense as $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: Exactly @Maximilian Janisch, the stationary distribution on the component can also be found by computing the left eigenvector of $P$ in the linear system $\pi=\pi P$, where $P$ is same as your $A$.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Sandipan: If you are in states $19, 20$ or $21$, there is no way to go to any other states. For these 3 states, you have the transition matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&\frac12&0\\ \frac12&0&\frac 12 \\ 0 & \frac12 & \frac12\end{pmatrix}.$$ (Formally, you can go from the original chain to this $3$-state chain and back using properties of block matrices.) The matrix $A$ is symmetric, so it is unitarily diagonalizable (cf. page 307 of [1]).

Using the standard diagonalization procedure (cf. page 236f. of [1]), we get $$A = S D S^{-1},$$ where $$S=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\\end{array}\right)$$ and $$D=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{array}\right)$$ and $$S^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{6} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\\end{array}\right).$$

Indeed we also notice that with respect to any norm on the space of $3\times 3$ matrices, $D^n\to\operatorname{diag}(0,0,1)$ for $n\to\infty$, so also as mentioned by Sandipan, as $n\to\infty$, we have $$A^n\to S\operatorname{diag}(0,0,1) S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac 13&\frac 13&\frac 13\\\frac 13&\frac 13&\frac 13\\\frac 13&\frac 13&\frac 13\end{pmatrix}.$$

Multiplying this with any $$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb R^3$$ gives $$\frac{a+b+c}3\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$ So indeed if we start with *any* probability measure on the states $19,20,21$ (i.e. $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c\in[0,1]$), we will end up asymptotically in equilibrium through this Markov chain.

---

Furthermore this gives an easy answer to question 3, you just need to compute $$S D^5 S^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}\frac12\\0\\\frac12\end{pmatrix}.$$

## Literature

[1]: Gerd Fischer, *Lineare Algebra*, edition 17 (2009).

Comment: Thank you very much! But how did you find the matrix S?

Comment: @Guest It is standard diagonalization: First calculate the eigenvalues of $A$, they are $-\frac 12,\frac 12, 1$. The corresponding eigenvectors are $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then the columns of $S$ are exactly those eigenvectors. Let me know if you need further help :)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful :-) I've uploaded a new picture. I would like to know how to solve question 7? Btw, I've already solved 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: @Guest120120 With all due respect, this is against the etiquette of this site, which is why I have just reverted your edit. If my answer was helpful, please accept it and post a new question. Also it would be nice to see your own thoughts on the questions instead of just "how do I solve this part of my homework?"